# Comparing Excel sheet data with PDF file in VBScript

Tags: excel, pdf, vbscript, converters, testcomplete

I have my application reports in Excel sheet and PDF file. Now my requirement is I want compare my Excel sheet reports to PDF file, I am facing problem with comparing these two files.

My reports are in table format so I am unable identify the rows and columns in PDF. Please give some suggestions about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no a direct way to compare data in PDF and Excel files. You need to separately read data from both a PDF report and from an Excel sheet and compare this data in your test. Find some information on how to read content of a PDF file in [Can I use TestComplete to compare PDF files?](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/8859/) FAQ article and search the [TestComplete forum](http://smartbear.com/forums/) - it contains a lot of discussions on how to work with PDF. Information on working with Excel files can be found in the [Working With Microsoft Excel Files](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/56927/) help topic.